# Как сделать такие уши как на скриншоте?

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать каким-то образом уши как на фото. С псевдоэлементами after, before - не получается никак.

```css
.main-advantages {
  background-color: #0099bd;
  height: 170px;
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.advan {
  float: left;
}

.advan-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  width: 154px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -24px;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.advan-image {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.main-advantages:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #7fddeb;
  height: 170px;
  width: 90px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-advantages">
  <div class="left-ear"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="advan">
      <div class="advan-image">
        <img src="assets/img/advan-triangle.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="advan-text">
        <p>Pellentesque placerat vehicula nisi maximus</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="advan">
      <div class="advan-image">
        <img src="assets/img/advan-triangle.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="advan-text">
        <p>Donec lobortis pharetra purus et eleifend</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="advan">
      <div class="advan-image">
        <img src="assets/img/advan-triangle.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="advan-text">
        <p>Aliquam tempus vestibulum massa eget faucibus</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-ear"></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста, люди добрые ))

Comment: и что такое уши?

Comment: это блоки по бокам разного цвета с отступами

Comment: Покажите, как именно у вас не получается с `before/after`

Comment: @br3t добавил в шапку вопроса

Comment: Добавьте html и css вашего `main-advantages`

Comment: @br3t добавил, желательно бы без after/before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуем так:

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.wrapper:after, .wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.wrapper .inner-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="inner-wrapper">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как-то без псевдоэлементов, и flex - а то я пока её не смотрел даже ?